# Room dao cannot resolve table name and method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-room

I'm trying to implement a simple database using Room and Dao, this is what I did
**My entity:**

```
public class Note {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;
}
```

I have also generated all getters and setters in the `entity` but I don't include here because it's very long.
**My Dao interface:**

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDAO {
    List<Note> getAllNotes();
}
```

**My database class:**

```
@Database(entities = Note.class, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class NoteDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static NoteDatabase noteDatabase;

    public static synchronized NoteDatabase getDatabase(Context context){
        if (noteDatabase == null){
            noteDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    NoteDatabase.class,
            );
        }
        return noteDatabase;
    }
}
```

When I use `List<Note> notes` and `notes.toString()`, it only shows me the date and time, the title is `null`, I also notice that in the `Dao interface`, it raises 2 errors which are `Cannot resolve symbol notes` and `Cannot resolve symbol id`. I don't understand why it doesn't insert to the database. Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you edit and add how you insert an example note as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have included in your question is fine (after adding the getters and setters) and then using:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NoteDatabase db;
    NoteDAO dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = NoteDatabase.getDatabase(this);
        dao = db.noteDAO();

        Note note1 = new Note();
        note1.setTitle("NOTE001");
        note1.setDatetime("2022-01-01 10:30");
        note1.setSubtitle("The First Note");
        note1.setWebsite("www.mynotes.com");
        note1.setNoteText("This is the note");
        note1.setColor("Black");
        note1.setImagePath("notes/note1.jpg");

        dao.insertNote(note1);
        for (Note n: dao.getAllNotes()) {
            Log.d("NOTEINFO","Title is " + n.getTitle() + " Date is " + n.getDatetime() + " blah blah ToString = " + n);
        }
    }
}
```

- note the only amendment to the code copied from the question is the use of `.allowMainThreadQueries` in the databaseBuilder.

The result being:-

```
D/NOTEINFO: Title is NOTE001 Date is 2022-01-01 10:30 blah blah ToString = NOTE001 : 2022-01-01 10:30
```

However, adding :-

```
    Note note2 = new Note();
    //note1.setTitle("NOTE001"); //<<<<<<<<<<< OOOPS
    note2.setDatetime("2022-01-01 10:30");
    note2.setSubtitle("The Second Note");
    note2.setWebsite("www.mynotes.com");
    note2.setNoteText("This is the note");
    note2.setColor("Black");
    note2.setImagePath("notes/note2.jpg");
```

Results in what you appear to be describing as per:-

```
D/NOTEINFO: Title is null Date is 2022-01-01 10:30 blah blah ToString = null : 2022-01-01 10:30
```

I believe you saying

> I also notice that in the Dao interface, it raises 2 errors which are Cannot resolve symbol notes and Cannot resolve symbol id

Is perhaps the clue to the cause, which could be that you have the incorrect dependencies you should have 2 for Room:-

1. the runtime library e.g. `implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0-alpha02'`, and
2. the compiler library e.g. `annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-alpha02'`

Another possibility is that in addition to the getters and setters you have a constructor that doesn't set correctly the **title** so it is left as null.